# MySQL on multiple tables to compare

Tags: mysql, sql

Support I have multiple tables (X,Y,Z) of the exact same structure.
The tables have a DATETIME field and a DATA field.
I want to extract and compare DATA values based on the same DATETIME for all tables. Assuming all tables have the same DATETIME values but different data.
What would the SQL statement be?

I can't get it to work. Here are tables:

Table: A

### DATETIME  | HIGH | LOW

### 01:00     | 0.1  | 2.4

### 02:00     | 0.2  | 3.0

### 03:00     | 0.8  | 0.7

### 04:00     | 1.3  | 1.1

Table: B

### DATETIME  | HIGH | LOW

### 01:00     | 0.1  | 2.4

### 02:00     | 0.2  | 3.0

### 03:00     | 0.8  | 0.7

### 04:00     | 1.3  | 1.1

Table: C

### DATETIME  | HIGH | LOW

### 01:00     | 0.1  | 2.4

### 02:00     | 0.2  | 3.0

### 03:00     | 0.8  | 0.7

### 04:00     | 1.3  | 1.1

Structure for all tables are the same. I want to retrieve data from all tables where their datetime are same.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for the JOIN operator.

`SELECT * FROM X JOIN Y ON X.datetime = Y.datetime JOIN Z on Y.datetime = Z.datetime`

This should give you rows with one datetime column and X.data, Y.data and Z.data columns.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Here are tables:
**Table: Actions**
Name  | Action       | Time
----------------------------
James | Ate an apple | 01:00
James | Kicked a dog | 02:00
Steve | Ate a dog    | 03:00
Steve | Kicked a hen | 01:00
Dave  | died         | 02:00

**Table: Items**
Name  | Item         | Time
----------------------------
James | Chainsaw     | 01:00
James | Hammer       | 01:05
James | Crowbar      | 01:10
Steve | Hammer       | 02:00
Steve | Egg          | 01:05
Dave  | Egg          | 01:05

Comment: I added another answer for the updated structure you provided in your question, with the resulting output table structure. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a new answer, seeing that your question changed.
You need to perform a join between those tables:

```
SELECT * FROM
(A JOIN B ON A.datetime = B.datetime)
JOIN C ON B.datetime = C.datetime
```

That will create a table with columns:

```
datetime | A.high | A.low | B.high | B.low | C.high | C.low
```